# Как уменьшить блок?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно уменьшить эти блоки(сделать в форме квадрата). Я пытался использовать margin-right и left, но не получалось.
html:

```
<div class="Block1">
                <img class="img7" src="images\wheels.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="p29">
                    Регулировка <br>
                    угла колёс
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="Block2">
                <img class="img8" src="images\oil.png" alt="">
                <p class="p29">
                    Регулировка <br>
                    угла колёс
                </p>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.p28 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.img7 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    
}

.Block1 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    box-shadow: -3px 0px 13px 9px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.p29 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.Block2 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    box-shadow: -3px 0px 13px 9px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.img8 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: сколько таких блоков будет? как они должны располагаться (по центру, слева, справа)?

Comment: 8 блоков, 4 на ряд, один сверху, а другой снизу

Comment: вся конструкция по центру